# How to position this element fixed?

Tags: html, css

MY HTML has a graphic element to the right that has a lighter color where info text is displayed:
[image]

The HTML for the element is

```
<div class="fl50" id="R-col">
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="fl95 hknot pin" style="height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
        <div class="fl20"><strong>S&ouml;kande</strong></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>





    <div class="fl100">
    1 
    <A HREF="javascript:doSubmitWithModifierAndIndex('Grunduppgifter','editPerson', '1', '0')" ><span class="link">Kenneth Branagh</span> (241, 268569)</A>
    (även uppfinnare)   
    <BR>
    Testvägen 3<BR>
    12121   Testby</div><div class="clear"></div>



        <div class="fl20"><strong>Uppfinnare</strong></div> 
            <div class="clear"></div>


    1 
    <A HREF="javascript:doSubmitWithModifierAndIndex('Grunduppgifter','editPerson', '2', '0')" ><span class="link">Kenneth Branagh</span> (241, 0)</A>
    (även sökande)  
    <BR>
    Testvägen 3<BR>
    12121   Testby<BR>




        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- sokupp -->
```

My CSS file is

```
*  {font-family:arial;}

.avnamn{ 
                color: #90002b; 
                font-size: 140%; 
                display: inline; 
                vertical-align: 3%; 
                margin-left: 1%;
                }

.b{border:1px solid #000;}

.readonly{background-color: #CCC;}

.Webdings{
    font-family: Webdings;
    }

ul{margin-top: 0px}

.mt3{margin-top:-3px;}
.mt5p{margin-top:5px;}

.fontS80 {font-size: 80%;} 
a:link{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:visited{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:hover{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:active{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }

.fontS75 {font-size: 75%;} 

.link{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;}

.link_sm{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;}

.link_sm{font-size: 70%;cursor: pointer;}

.small{font-size: 75%;}

.smallg{font-size: 75%;
color: #555;}

.ssmall{
    font-size: 65%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
}
.small60{font-size: 60%;}
.small50{
    font-size: 50%;
    color: #333;
}
.smallb{font-size: 85%;}
table{display:inline;}

h1{font-size: 130%;display:inline;}
h2{font-size: 100%;display:inline;}
h3{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h4{font-size: 70%;display:inline;}
h5{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hthin{
    font-size: 125%;
}

.th {text-align: left;}

td, th{font-size: 75%;
    vertical-align: text-top;}
.td_link{cursor: pointer;}
.td40{height:40px;}
.td60{height:60px;}



.thkant{
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 70%;
        text-align: left;
}

.labb{F0F0E3; c1c1b3 }

.bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
.bbV{border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_nbA {background-color:#CCC;}
.TB_bt, .TB_nb, .TB_db, .TB_bb {background-color:#efefdc;}

.hk {background-color:#d9ddb3;}

.hknot {background-color:#f9faf2;}
/*<!--F8F8F1-->*/
.TB_bt{border-top: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bt5{border-top: 5px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
.TB_bb2{border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;}
.TB_db{border-bottom: 1px solid #000; border-top: 1px solid #000;}
.TB_tb{border-top: 2px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo{border: 2px solid #efefdc;}
.TB_bo_hk{border-top: 1px solid #efefdc;}


.TB_bo2{border: 1px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo2B{
border-top: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
border-left: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-right: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
}

.TD_bo{
    border-right: 1px solid #c1c1b3;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.TD_bo2{

    border-right: 0;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ytb{
    border-left:3px solid #efefdc;
    border-right:3px solid #efefdc;
}

.datum {
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: text-top;} 
.sub {background:#EAEAEA;}
.sub_meny, .sub_meny_r, .sub_meny_active, .sub_meny_sm{
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: text-top;}

.sub_meny_sm {
    font-size: 60%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}   

.sub_meny_r{
    float:right;
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;}

.sub_meny_rm{margin-top:4px;}
.sub_meny_active{font-weight: bold;}

.flikkant1 {
    background-image: url(../images/fl1k.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    z-index: -1;}

.inl_namn{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: Black;
    text-decoration: none;}

.th{text-align: left;}
.tr{text-align: right;}

.g1{
    background-color: #FFF;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g2{
    background-color: #EEE;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g3{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.g4{
    background-color: #CCC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.popup{
    border-color: #000; 
    border-style: groove; 
    border-width: 2px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 70%;
}

.popupN{
    background-color: #F0F0E3;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.pin{padding: 6px;}

.fl10, .fl20, .fl30, .fl40, .fl50, .fl60, .fl70, .fl80, .fl90, .fl100 {
    padding-bottom:4px;color: #000000;
}

.over{
    background-color: #EFEFDC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.half{
line-height:50%;
}

.quarter{
line-height:25%;
}

.lh10{
line-height:10%;
}

.checkmargin {margin-right: 25px;}  
.checkmarginL {margin-left: 25px;}  

.pusher {padding-left: 15px;"}
.pusherR {margin-right: 40px;"}

.rand3{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 3px;}
.rand1{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 1px;}

.whiteborder {     color: #ffffff;      border: 4px solid #ffffff;      padding: 10px;      margin: 10px; }
#details { width: 580; color: #ffffff; }

.f200 {
    color: #000000;
}

.f210 {
    color: #000000;float: left;
}

.b2{border:2px solid #efefdc;}
.inp_sel{width: 80%;}


.form-bg {
  background: #eeefdf;
  width:1080px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.data-bar {
  border-bottom:1px solid #fbfbf7;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 10px;
}

.left {
float:left;
width:200px;

}

.column1 {     margin: 0;      padding: 0;     width: 450px;     border:0;     float: left; } 
.column2 {     color:black; margin: 0;      padding: 0;     border:0;     width: 50px;     float: right; }

.right {
float:right;
width:700px;
}

.data-box-nat {
width:650px;
height:100px;
border:2px solid #cbcbcb;
margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
.data-box-pct {
width:650px;
height:100px;
border:2px solid #cbcbcb; 
}
.data-box {
width:650px;
height:100px;
border:2px solid #cbcbcb; 
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.data-box-country {
width:650px;
border:2px solid #cbcbcb; 
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#table td { 
margin:120px; 
} 

.personName {     float:left;     width:300px;   }  
.otherDetails {     float:right;     width:300px;      }

a img     { border: 0;}
```

My problem is that when I resize the page the right column element "drops" down below and I'd prefer it not to float but stay at its place when the page gets resized. Can it be done?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this can help you? http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/W9zjy/)

the key is to not let the parent container to go smaller than the total width of the inner containers.  So, set the min-width of the parent container to a size greater or equal to the inner ones.